# Using spread operator and combining arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to combine multiple arguments into a single, readable text line, so that I can write it out to a file. But, I can't figure out how to do it:

```
const fs = require('fs');
var stream = fs.createWriteStream('test.txt');

let log = function(...data) {
    console.log(...data); // one 2 three (that's how it should be)
    stream.write(...data); // one
    stream.write('\n');
};

stream.once('open', function() {
    log('one', 2, 'three');
    stream.close();
});
```

How should I correctly capture all parts of 'data' concisely in *stream.write*, without writing some long function to do it?

Comment: Your issue here is that `stream.write()` is not expecting multiple data arguments as in `stream.write(data1, data2, data3)`.  In fact, the 2nd and 3rd arguments are supposed to be encoding and callback.  So, you have to either combine your multiple arguments into one string or call `stream.write()` separately for each argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
let log = function(...data) {
    ...
};
```

data is an array.

If you want an array that looks like `['one', 2, 'three']` to print like `one 2 three`, you do

```
let log = function(...data) {
    const str = data.join(' ');
    console.log(str);
};
```

Comment: Yes of course! I had tried that but for some reason was trying to use the spread, (...data).join(' ') which wouldn't work!